# Is it a good idea to track jobs using the linking mechanism in erlang?

Tags: erlang

I'm writing a map reduce implementation using erlang.

In order to get notified that the mapping has fully finished (all data has been processed), I'm creating a link between the workers that performs the actual mapping and the "manager process" which will trap the `EXIT` signals from the workers, and sees if the reason is `normal`. If so, it will consider the job was properly run. If not, based on the `Pid`, it will determine the job that has failed and spawns another worker for that job (I will keep a book of `Pid`s of the workers). Once `EXIT` signals with Reason=normal from all `Pid` has been received, the mapping is fully done.

My question is, 1) is this safe? and 2) is this a good practice?
Btw the jobs are idempotent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this approach sounds good so far.

But you shouldn't implement it itself but instead use a [supervisor](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/sup_princ.html).

The [simple_one_for_one](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/sup_princ.html#id71482) type of supervisor implements almost exactly the same behavour that you described.